# how to get refreshed shipping address in quote object in js - Magento2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cache, quote

I am using this one code but once i update shipping info not getting refreshed info they retrieve old info how can i achieve that?

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
], function($, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {
    $('#target').on('click', function(e) {
        var address = quote.shippingAddress();
        console.log(address);
        // clearing cached rates to retrieve new ones
        rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);

        console.log(quote.shippingAddress()); // but getting old one 
        var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();
        if (type) {
            customerAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
        } else {
            newAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you updating shipping info? If you're changing the form element value with jquery val() or something, you need to trigger change on the element for the shipping rates observer to pick up the updated values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
    ], function($, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {
        $('#target').on('click', function(e) {
            var address = quote.shippingAddress();
            console.log(address);

            // reload address information
            address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();

            // clearing cached rates to retrieve new ones
            rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);

            console.log(quote.shippingAddress()); // but getting old one 
            var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();
            if (type) {
                customerAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
            } else {
                newAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you tell me this which js file path, thank you @bramulous

Comment: Am having this exception "Property \"TriggerReload\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressInterface\"." once I imlement above "address.trigger_reload "

Comment: I have the same issue updated shipping address not showing on checkout. please help

Comment: I am trying to refresh the sidebar but not working . Any solutions?